# How to parallelise a while loop in bash?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have the following `while` loop that runs in parallel. (  The `logProcess` is a function that I define earlier in my script. )

```
while read LINE; do
    logProcess $LINE &
done <<< "$ELS_LOGS"
wait
```

I need to find a way to limit the number of processes running. I know there are parallel processes running. How do I convert the loop to use that command?

Comment: maybe inside the loop , you can check for ps -ef and grep the *log* process and check the number of lines [wc -l] . if that is more than the number of processes you want to run, you can sleep for sometime until one of the processes has completed and then start the new logProcess again.

is that what is required?

Comment: `logProcess $LINE`, not `logProcess "$LINE"`? Keep in mind that if you have a line that contains a `*`, you'll get a list of filenames put on your command line.

Answer (score 6):

May I recommend **GNU Parallel** to you. Your entire script would become:

```
parallel -a "$ELS_LOGS" logProcess
```

If `logProcess` is a function defined within your script, you will need to export it first before running **GNU Parallel**, like this:

```
export -f logProcess
```

Then if you want, say, 8 running at a time, you simply do:

```
parallel -j 8 -a "$ELS_LOGS" logProcess
```

If you want to see what it would do, without actually doing anything:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

If you want a progress bar, or an ETA:

```
parallel --eta ...
parallel --bar ...
```

Comment: The script contains more functions and cannot run as above. Ideally i need to just parallelise the loop part.

Comment: Not sure I understand - what I suggest is identical to what you asked for. Is your question not representative of what you want?

Comment: @MatthewBullock, if your function calls other functions, *export those other functions as well*. By contrast, if your functions need to modify global, shared state, then you have a job you can't do in shell (without using disk or another external store for coordination): Shell doesn't support threads (where you have multiple lines of execution sharing the same variable states); instead, *all* its options are multiprocessing-style, where each subprocess has its own variables, working directory, etc.

Answer (score 1):

GNU `xargs` is also an adequate tool for the job:

```
xargs -P 20 -d $'\n' -n 1 logProcess
```

...will run up to 20 concurrent `logProcess` instances, with each line of the stdin given to `xargs` passed to a different such instance.